# Concerning tails os and proxychains - getting denied connection

Tags: linux, tor, socks, tails-os, proxychains

I've been trying to run a wallet app in tails os ver 4.28 with no success. I'm getting denied error when using it with proxychains. Being a noob here, would someone assist me in letting me know what I'm doing incorrect here. I've included terminal & proxychain config info for reference here.

```
amnesia@amnesia:~/Persistent$ chmod +x Neuron-v0.101.2-x86_64.AppImage
amnesia@amnesia:~/Persistent$ proxychains ./Neuron-v0.101.2-x86_64.AppImage 
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-127.0.0.1:8114-<--denied
06:16:58.553 › Network: connection dropped
|DNS-request| localhost 
|DNS-request| localhost 
|DNS-response| localhost is 127.0.0.1
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-|DNS-request| localhost 
<><>-127.0.0.1:8114-<--denied
|DNS-response| localhost is 127.0.0.1
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-127.0.0.1:8114-|DNS-request| localhost 
<--denied
06:17:00.145 › Network: fail to connect to the network. Is CKB node running?
06:17:00.323 › Network: switched to: {
  id: 'mainnet',
  name: 'default node',
  remote: 'http://localhost:8114',
  genesisHash: '0x92b197aa1fba0f63633922c61c92375c9c074a93e85963554f5499fe1450d0e5',
  type: 0,
  chain: 'ckb'
}
06:17:01.453 › Main window: The main window is ready to show
|DNS-response| localhost is 127.0.0.1
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-|DNS-request| localhost 
<><>-127.0.0.1:8114-<--denied
|DNS-response| localhost is 127.0.0.1
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-127.0.0.1:8114-|DNS-request| localhost 
<--denied
|DNS-response| localhost is 127.0.0.1
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-127.0.0.1:8114-<--denied
|DNS-response| localhost is 127.0.0.1
|DNS-request| localhost 
|DNS-request| localhost 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-127.0.0.1:8114-<--denied
06:17:03.705 › CKB: external RPC on default uri not detected, starting bundled CKB node.
06:17:03.707 › CKB: Initializing node...
06:17:03.708 › CKB: init: config file detected, skip ckb init.
06:17:03.708 › CKB: starting node...
06:17:04.116 › CKB: process closed
|DNS-response| localhost is 127.0.0.1
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-|DNS-request| localhost 
<><>-127.0.0.1:8114-<--denied
|DNS-response| localhost is 127.0.0.1
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-127.0.0.1:8114-<--denied
|DNS-request| localhost 
|DNS-response| localhost is 127.0.0.1
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-127.0.0.1:8114-|DNS-request| localhost 
<--denied
^C|DNS-response|: localhost does not exist
Aborted
```

proxychain.config file

```
#dynamic_chain
strict_chain
#random_chain
#chain_len = 2
#quiet_mode
proxy_dns 

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks4  127.0.0.1 9050
```

Appreciate any assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, didn't get a response from the community as of yet. I did some exploration and enabled the following in proxychains config file

- enabled dynamic_chain and commented strict_chain
- replace socks4 with socks5

This got rid of the denied issue, but gave me a timeout issue.
Reached out the wallet tech team for assistance. They responded stating wallet synchronization fails when it's behind a firewall, vpn, anti-virus. Wallet behind a proxy configuration also disrupts the synchronization. I had a very slim hope that this would work and that faded quicky with their response. This closes out this open question.